# Move list item to folder right after creating it

Tags: jquery, wss-3.0

I'm trying to override the save button in a SharePoint Services 3.0 form when adding a new list item. I thought that this would be easy with jQuery but I have too many fields in my form and from various types (text, radio, check boxes, date & time, etc) and went crazy trying to obtain all the values. I know that there should be an easier way to crack this nut.

First, I'm using jQuery, SPServices and the PreSaveAction function to create a folder before the item is submitted. This works ok.

Second, I can't figure out how to create/move the item inside the recently created folder. I'm aware that using the BaseName or RootFolder could do the trick, but I can't get to edit them before the item is submitted.

Does anybody know how to overcome this issue?, as you may imagine I'm desperate to find the solution having looked in way too many blogs and forums already to keep hitting the wall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by first landing to a page that does the folder creation before getting to the SharePoint form page. At the form page I receive the folder name in a query string parameter.
I guess the simplest option ends up being the best solution.